# Does the JVM force garbage collection when it reaches its -Xmx limit?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

The question is basically contained in the title.

Say you have an application that has reached its JVM -Xmx limit. When that application requires more memory is garbage collection forced ? (in the HotSpot JVM)

A second odd thing I can't explain is that I currently have an application server which is ran with -Xmx=2048m, the "top" command (on linux) reports 2.7g for its process.

So how/when is an application allowed to exceed its -Xmx ?

Thanks,

Comment: `-Xmx=2048` is 2048 bytes.  I assume you mean `-Xmx=2048m` Note: You can write just `-mx2g` which is the same thing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, yes I meant 2048m. Edited the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually the normal GC is triggered when young generation is full (not the whole heap) and major GC is triggered when there is no space left in survivor space so some objects need to be migrated to old generation.

Comment: +1: Usually a full tenured space is what triggers a Full GC.  Minor collections usually avoid the survivor space filling by moving objects to the tenured space before this happens.

Comment: The `-Xmx` only sets the maximum heap size.  This is often the biggest area, but not the only area. You have thread stacks, direct memory, shared libraries, the JVM itself etc.

Answer (score 7):

The Xmx parameter does only specify the size of the heap. The Java process takes more memory since the heap is only one part of the Java process, I guess you also have other stuff that the java process contains like native libraries, the perm gen and also native memory allocations made by the application.

Here's an nice article describing memory allocation:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the JVM will certainly call the GC if it reaches the heap limit (and probably much sooner). If this doesn't help, it will throw `OutOfMemoryError`s.

The reason why you are seeing a bigger process memory consumption is that the `-Xmx` option only limits the Java heap space (where the Java objects are allocated on). There are several other memory regions used by the JVM additionally: space for Thread stacks, the "PermGen" (where the classes and their code is stored), "direct" memory allocated via `ByteBuffers`, memory allocated by native libraries, etc. For some of these additional memory regions there exist other configuration options which allow to limit them, for example `-Xss`, but some are even out of control of the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually the case, althought GC is normally triggered much sooner, depending on the Garbage Collector you use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you don't still find memory it will raise OutOfmemory Error. I understand it like this.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the guarantee is that a full GC will be performed before an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown. Since exceeding the heap size limit must result in such an error, that implies you'll always have at least one full GC run when the limit is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is quite a large area, but what you say is correct for full collections (there are other types)

One thing to be aware of is that -Xmx sets the maximum heap size but there is also an -Xms, which is the minumum heap size. Your application may start with only the minimum configured. Then if the memory used reaches that, it will trigger a full garbage collection AND increase the amount of heap available, from the minimum (-Xmx) up to some value less than or equal to the maximum (-Xmx). This can happen several times, until the maximum is reached. After that, it cannot increase the heap anymore but garbage collections will continue to happen when that maximum is reached.